# AJAX PHP DATABASE DropDown List Fill Insert Image

Tags: php, html

how do i add the img src = in that code? thanks in advance

```
 function fill_product($connect)  
 {  

  $output = '';  
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblstdpro";  
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
  {  
       $output .= '<div class="col-md-3">';  
       $output .= '<div style="border:1px solid #ccc; padding:20px; margin-bottom:20px;">'.$row["StdImage"].'</br>'.$row["StdID"].'</br>'.$row["Fname"].' '.$row["Lname"].'';  
       $output .=     '</div>';  
       $output .=     '</div>';  
  }  
  return $output;  
 }
```

How can i put the image src in

```
 '.$row["StdImage"].'
```

Comment: Put the HTML around it.

Comment: how ? can you give me an example

Comment: Something like `"><img src="'.$row["StdImage"].'" />`

Comment: thanks you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
 { 
     $image = $row["StdImage"];
     $output .= '<div class="col-md-3">';  
     $output .= '<div style="border:1px solid #ccc; padding:20px; margin-bottom:20px;"><img src="'.$image.'"></br>'.$row["StdID"].'</br>'.$row["Fname"].' '.$row["Lname"].'';  
     $output .=     '</div>';  
     $output .=     '</div>'; 
}
```

what i have done is stored the value of your image in `$image` variable and used it like `<img src="'.$image.'">`